# GIS Map 3D Animation in Anylogic

Tags: 3d, gis, anylogic

I need to get a 3D Animation view of a model running over a GIS Map on Anylogic. It allows me to create the 3D window but it doesn't show any agent as it seems the GIS Map element can't be animated in 3D. Is there any way around this? Felipe? Benjamin?. If not, do you know of any good 3D integration with Anylogic to do such a thing?

Comment: not possible with current tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the GIS map is inherently 2D, that cannot be changed.

There is no way around it afaik. You can connect AnyLogic to the Unity engine (2019 AL conf paper talked about it) but that is just replicating the 3D window with fancier visuals. Won't help with GIS.